# change block format in QtextEditor

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to change block format into QtextEditor but not able to figure out any method.

Issue: sometime due to tab or space issue between string Regex match return -1. I tried with line
number but "\n" is not consistent many block so older block highlight

In brief, is it possible to change format of multiline string.

Input Data :

```
begin
    # Date:         8/18/2021
    # Modified:     t00
    # User:         user3
    # Expiration:   t00
    # Justification:        Keep this wildcard waiver for test
    
    # Date:     10/12/2021
    # Modified: t00
    # User:     use1
    # Expiration:   t00
    # Justification:        testing
    
end
```

Expected:

```
begin
    # Date:         8/18/2021
    # Modified:     t00
    # User:         user3
    # Expiration:   t00
    # Justification:        Keep this wildcard waiver for test
    
    *# Date:        10/12/2021 (change format)
    # Modified: t00
    # User:     use1
    # Expiration:   t00
    # Justification:        testing*
    
end
```

```
def change_block_format(cls, text_editor, pattern):
        """
        changing block format based on pattern
        :param input_text: string which contain all text
        :param pattern: string pattern which need to search
        :return:
        """
    pattern = QRegExp(pattern)
    index = pattern.indexIn(text_editor.toPlainText())
    length = pattern.matchedLength()
    #cursor = QTextCursor(text_editor.document())
    print (pattern, index, length)
    for char_position in range(index, index+length, 1):
        cursor = QTextCursor(text_editor.document().findBlock(char_position))
        cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.EndOfLine, QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)
        cursor.mergeCharFormat(GuiUtil.underline_format())
```

Input :

```
# Date:     10/12/2021 (change format)
        # Modified: t00
        # User:     use1
        # Expiration:   t00
        # Justification:        testing*
```

Comment: your question is unclear

Comment: I have input string and would like to change multiline format. if I search by date than i can have common data into multiple place. So I create single multiple line string which contain all information but problem is,  "There is tab and space issue into : " so pattern did not match